# Usando Store Procedure para Autenticação de Usuários

Tags: mysql, asp, stored-procedures

Tenho a seguinte `Store Procedure` no meu banco de dados MySQL, `SP_Autentica`:

```
BEGIN
SET @id = (SELECT ID FROM userdata WHERE Username = user AND Password = pass);
END
```

No código ASP, `conn.asp`:

```
connectstr = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};SERVER=" & db_server & ";PORT=" & db_port &  ";DATABASE=" & db_name & ";UID=" & db_username & ";PWD=" & db_userpassword & ";OPTION=" & db_option

Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Open connectstr
```

No código ASP, `CheckUser.asp`:

```
<!-- #include file="../assets/commonFiles/conn.asp" -->

varUsername = Request("Username")
varPassword = Request("Password")

cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.CommandText = SP_Autentica
cmd.CommandType = 4
p = cmd.Parameters
p.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@user","@pass"))
cmd("@user") = varUsername
cmd("@pass") = varPassword
cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn
cmd.Execute()
```

Gostaria de receber a resposta deste `SELECT` da `Procedure` em uma variável, quando o usuário enviar os parâmetros de `user` e `pass`. Mas recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01b6' Object doesn't support
>   this property or method: 'cmd.CommandText' /login/CheckUserSP.asp,
>   line 55

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Cara, será que pra setar o cmd vc não teria que fazer `set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")`?

Comment: Diego, isso já está na 3a linha depois do "include file".

Comment: Tá faltando o set na frente

Comment: Obrigado! Desse ponto passou, agora não está conseguindo adicionar os parameters:

Comment: Posta o erro senão fica difícil de ajudar

Comment: Provider error '80020005'

Type mismatch.

/login/CheckUserSP.asp, line 58

Comment: Linha 58: cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@user","@pass"))

Comment: A criação de parâmetros segue o seguinte forma: cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("RetVal", adInteger, _
      adParamReturnValue)

Comment: Alterado agora recebi o seguinte erro: ADODB.Command error '800a0bb9'

Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.

/login/CheckUserSP.asp, line 57

Comment: Pq o seu não é integer. Coloca o tipo referente ao que tá no bd

Comment: Alterei para:

cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("RetVal", adVarChar, adParamReturnValue))

No meu banco são dois campos VarChar..e quero retornar um coluna Integer

Recebo a mensagem de erro:

ADODB.Command error '800a0bb9'

Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.

/login/CheckUserSP.asp, line 57